# F#: Quotation with type definition?

Tags: f#, quotations

I'm playing around with quotations and I can't see an expression pattern for type definitions. Is there really not one, or am I missing something?

```
<@@ type MyType (name:string) =
    member x.Name = name @@>
```

Gives "Unexpected keyword 'type' in quotation literal."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. You can only quote code, that is to say, any [valid F# expression](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc264041877). Type definitions are not considered as code, but definitions.

What you might want to do is put `ReflectedDefinition` attribute on a type members:

```
type MyType (name : string) =
    [<ReflectedDefinition>] member x.Name = name
```

If you want to retrieve the AST of members that have `ReflectedDefinition` you can use `Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition` function.

E.g, this sample code prints ASTs of all reflected definition members of `MyType`:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open System.Reflection

type MyType (name : string) =
    [<ReflectedDefinition>] member x.Name = name

let mis = typeof<MyType>.GetMembers()
for mi in mis do
    try
        match Expr.TryGetReflectedDefinition(mi :?> MethodBase) with
        | Some(e) ->  printfn "%A" e
        | None    -> ()
    with _ -> ()
()
```